# Create and populate Varray in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, varray

I'm trying to créate a Varray of beans type and populate it, but I'm in a hurry and don't find any usefull example.

```
arr=[[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]
```

This is my code:

```
 create table my_table (NUM_OPERACIO NUMBER,TITULS varchar2(3)) ;
 insert into my_table values(1,'A');
 insert into my_table values(2,'B');
 insert into my_table values(3,'C');

 create TYPE item IS object( NUM_OPERACIO NUMBER, TITULS varchar2(3)); 
 /
 create TYPE arr IS VARRAY(10) OF item;
 /

 insert into arr values( select NUM_OPERACIO, TITULS from my_table);

 FOR i IN 1..3 loop
     dbms_output.put_line(arr (i));
 END loop;
```

Help me achive this, please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
create table my_table (NUM_OPERACIO NUMBER,TITULS varchar2(3)) ;
insert into my_table values(1,'A');
insert into my_table values(2,'B');
insert into my_table values(3,'C');

CREATE TYPE item IS object( NUM_OPERACIO NUMBER, TITULS varchar2(3)); 
/
CREATE TYPE item_array IS VARRAY(10) OF item;
/
```

**PL/SQL**:

```
DECLARE
  arr item_array;
BEGIN
  SELECT item( NUM_OPERACIO,TITULS )
  BULK COLLECT INTO arr
  FROM   my_table;

  FOR i IN 1..arr.COUNT loop
    dbms_output.put_line(arr(i).NUM_OPERACIO || ', ' || arr(i).TITULS);
  END loop;
END;
/
```